# Extract specific links with webclient class

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to extract urls from youtube playlist using WebClient class.
What I tried is:

```
Dim wc As New WebClient
    Dim html As String = wc.DownloadString("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368")
    Dim links As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(html, "<a.*?href=""(.*?)"".*?>(.*?)</a>")
    For Each match As Match In links
        Dim matchUrl As String = match.Groups(1).Value

        If matchUrl.StartsWith("/watch?v=") Then

            RichTextBox1.AppendText(matchUrl)
        End If
    Next
```

but unfortunately the richtextbox stays empty.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Regex doesn't match the source in any way.

Taking a look at the source you download from YouTube you can see that the links are not in `<a>` tags, but in JSON format

A fragment from the Url you linked:

```
  "title": {
    "runs": [
      {
    "text": "Peter Tosh - Legalize It"
      }
    ],
    "accessibility": {
      "accessibilityData": {
    "label": "Peter Tosh - Legalize It by Bondade Ã© Nosso HÃ¡bito 8 years ago 4 minutes, 46 seconds"
      }
    }
  },
  "index": {
    "simpleText": "1"
  },
  "shortBylineText": {
    "runs": [
      {
    "text": "Bondade Ã© Nosso HÃ¡bito",
    "navigationEndpoint": {
      "clickTrackingParams": "CD0QxjQYACITCMn2heSTz-wCFUmw1Qod1hMDdw==",
      "commandMetadata": {
        "webCommandMetadata": {
          "url": "/user/Bruno12170",
          "webPageType": "WEB_PAGE_TYPE_CHANNEL",
          "rootVe": 3611
        }
      },
      "browseEndpoint": {
        "browseId": "UCY1IJY2IYNVfD7R-JbgQGbQ",
        "canonicalBaseUrl": "/user/Bruno12170"
      }
    }
      }
    ]
  },
  "lengthText": {
    "accessibility": {
      "accessibilityData": {
    "label": "4 minutes, 46 seconds"
      }
    },
    "simpleText": "4:46"
  },
  "navigationEndpoint": {
    "clickTrackingParams": "CD0QxjQYACITCMn2heSTz-wCFUmw1Qod1hMDdzIKcGxwcF92aWRlb1okVkxQTDRfRHg4OGRwdTdlcGZINnlid3FKcGY5dUwydEFsMzY4mgEDEPos",
    "commandMetadata": {
      "webCommandMetadata": {
    "url": "/watch?v=j6QkVTx2d88&list=PL4_Dx88dpu7epfH6ybwqJpf9uL2tAl368&index=1",
    "webPageType": "WEB_PAGE_TYPE_WATCH",
    "rootVe": 3832
      }
```

Based on understanding that you want to find the video Url, you can use the Regex:

```
Dim links As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(html, "\/watch\?v=[\w*\\u0026=]*")
```

You may want to include the line:

```
matchUrl = matchUrl.Replace("\u0026", "&")
```

to remove put the Ampersands (&) back in to the Url

Comment: Hi JayV, since there are other videos in my playlist, which got the same html, is my for each loop okay in this case? Also I want to ask you which kind of regex should I use to get also the title of songs? Thanks

Comment: @24343424 Given that you want to do more than just extract a video url, I think you would be better off trying to do this stuff with a JSON parser

Comment: I'm trying to look for some example, but I want to ask you how did you manage to format json code in such a readable code in your answer?

Comment: Also, If I would like just to exract video url, how should I modify my for each loop? Thanks

Comment: A quick google search for "json formatter" led me to this site: https://jsonformatter.org/

Comment: Using the updated Regex will help you find all matching lines. They should be populated in to the RichTextbox